# What does 0 mean in indexOf?

Tags: javascript

While I am writing some JavaScript, I came across a new code "indexOf". After read [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683295/why-is-this-indexof-call-returning-1) I thought its behaviour is as shown below but it seems not true. Can someone kindly give me an explanation about "indexOf", please?

false = -1;
true = 0 and more?

I have tried to change -1 to 0 and more but then nothing happens. Just to have a better understanding about jquery/indexOf.

what I have now,

```
$(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

it search for match(es) of "keyword" from "td_word",
if it is not false (!== -1, thus true) display:visible;,
if it is not true (false) display:hide;.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So… what’s the question? Is it “why does `indexOf` return `-1` sometimes?

Comment: And of what relevance to JavaScript's `indexOf` is a prior question regarding C#???

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not a jQuery method.

Comment: Andrew, with the way you put it. I would then ask, what numbers can indexOf return? (-1, 0, 1) only or more?

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit, may I ask if you have a link for the bloomin' documentation you mentioned?    I am not sure what you are talking about on C#. I tagged jquery only before Bergi edited.

Comment: Thank you Bergi. Is it just javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`array.indexOf(element)` returns the index of the element in the array. Read the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as well.

It was designed to return `-1` when the element doesn't exist, because `0` would mean that the element is in the 0th index (1st element).

### Examples :

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

array.indexOf('a') //0
array.indexOf('c') //2
array.indexOf('f') //-1, because it doesn't exist in array
```

---

From what I understand in your wording, I think that you think that `indexOf` is used to check if a certain element exists in an array. That is just a "side-effect" of `indexOf` but its actual usage is getting the index of an element in the array.

Comment: Thanks Mark. You made it more understandable!!      So all the elements are 0-base index or it depends? At the moment I know that table in jquery is a 0-base index.

Comment: @Maki - By default, all arrays in JavaScript have 0-based indices. Take note that objects are not arrays though.