# How to evaluate "if" comparison condition which fails when array index value is 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote an if condition where the return value is the `indexOf` an array. The if condition is failing when the first object of the array is returned (index of which is 0). Is there any way to fix this?

I'm checking if the value `term` is present in the array.

My code is:

```
if (array.indexOf(term)) {
    //do something
}
else {
    alert("error");
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're running into a null exception of some sort.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is in java, but it explains the same concept (just adapt it to javascript)

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis. Was that a copy/paste error?

Comment: if(array.indexOf(term)>-1) is the usual way.

Comment: @Jason yeah a copy paste error. corrected it.

Comment: @pal You fixed it wrong. The parenthesis belongs on the first line.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755645/indexof-with-if-statement-why-is-it-1-and-not-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because [`0` is falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript. Consider this sample:

```
if (0) {
    console.log("will never run");
}
```

That `log()` call will, as implied, never run.

You can do something like:

```
if(array.indexOf(term) > -1) { 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Or a more meaningful comparison, depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf()` function returns the index of the element in the array. If it's not found, it will return a -1. Thus you must check if `indexOf()` returns a value greater than -1. If true, it is in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the bitwise NOT operator ([`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT)) to quickly check whether the index of something means it contains it or not. For instance...

```
if(~[].indexOf('no')) { // Evaluates to 0
    console.log('Bitwise NOT of -1 evalautes to true'); // It doesn't
} else if (~['test'].indexOf('test')) { // Evaluates to something other than 0
    console.log('Bitwise NOT of 0 evalautes to true'); // It does
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is "fast" or "slow" in JavaScript but it's certainly valid

Comment: @jdphenix I guess instead of quick, I meant terse haha.